# find and validate specific values in Array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I need to validate that ONLY the following values are acceptable-  if the user provides `Home Address` for instance the script needs to Update the doc and `$push` Validation field...something like:
"Validation": "Addresses element failed validation |Address.type values: Mailing Address, Billing Address ".

```
{  
   "Addresses":[  
      {  
         "type":"Mailing Address"
      },
      {  
         "type":"Billing Address"
      }
   ]
}
```

In addition, the array doesn't have to have both Address types...there could be either ONLY "Mailing Address" or "Billing Address", or none (empty array). But once the type is provided - it must contain the above types only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the document validator feature provided by mongoDB.

```
db.createCollection( "your collection name",
   { validator: { $or:
      [
         { "Addresses": { $exits: true } },
         { "Addresses.type": { $in: [ "Mailing Address", "Billing Address" ] } }
      ]
   }
} )
```

so this ensures that addresses field exists and it contains mailing address or billing address. if anything apart from this is passed it throw error.

you can control validation levels also. go through the page for a good understanding on how mongo document validator works.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/document-validation/

Comment: Thank you @satish. However I need to $push the "Validation" field as mentioned above.

Comment: validator validates document when you are either inserting or updating a document. so $push will be taken care when you are updating the document.